# Timthumb.php Rewrite Seo Friendly URL (Nginx)

Tags: nginx

I started using nginx today.

These codes was working well rewrite on Apache.

```
RewriteRule ^thumb/(.*)x(.*)_(.*) styles/timthumb.php?src=http://image.mysite.org/uploads/$3&h=$2&w=$1&zc=1 [NC,L]
```

Url structure like this

```
http://www.mysite.org/styles/timthumb.php?src=http://image.mysite.org/uploads/fasulye.jpg&h=134&w=228&zc=1
```

To

> http://www.mysite.org/thumb/228x134_fasulye.jpg

I want make friendly seo link of thimtumb with Nginx. Please help me. :(

Sorry my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change much of the apache format

```
rewrite ^thumb/(.*)x(.*)_(.*) styles/timthumb.php?src=http://image.mysite.org/uploads/$3&h=$2&w=$1&zc=1 last;
```

Comment: 404 not found ? can you send full config with local

Comment: location /media/resizer/ {
   rewrite ^/(.*)x(.*)/r/(.*) /timthumb.php?src=http://$3&h=$2&w=$1&zc=1 last;
  }